# How to do the smallest match in regex replace even if the editor does not support non-greedy match

Tags: regex, replace, non-greedy

I using regex search to replace the following string:

```
\new{}\new{\textbf{test1}}\new{test2}
```

with

```
\textbf{test1}test2
```

I used regex replace with \new{(.*)} to find and \1 to replace.

however the search always match the whole line of my original string and the replace reuslt is:

```
}\new{\textbf{test1}}\new{test2
```

far from what I need.

In regex expression in Java, you can use a ? after a quantifier makes it a reluctant quantifier. It then tries to find the smallest match. So in java, my search regex expression would be

```
\\new\{(.*?)\}
```

I need the corresponding regex search string in TeXStudio to do the smallest match. Anyway to still work through for this case even if TexStudio does not support non-greed match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how deep the nesting goes at tis deepest? Can a new be nested in a new?

If the answers are 'yes' and 'no' there is a solution: in Robin's solution `\\new\{([^}]*)\}` replace the `[^}]*` with, for example, `[^{}]*({[^{}]*})?[^{}]*` which is "any number of characters that are not `{}`" followed by maybe an opening bracket, a number of non-brackets, and a closing one, followed by again zero or more not-brackets. This will match nesting up to two. For every extra level of nesting, you need to replace the middle `[^{}]*` with another `[^{}]*({[^{}]*})?[^{}]*` leading to fun like `\\new\{[^{}]*({[^{}]*({[^{}]*({[^{}]*})?[^{}]*})?[^{}]*})?[^{}]*\}` (4 levels).

[Example for 2 levels](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%5Cnew%5C%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%28%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%7D%29?%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%5C%7D&input=%5Cnew%7B%7D%5Cnew%7B%5Ctextbf%7Btest1%7D%7D%5Cnew%7Btest2%7D)
[Example for 4 levels](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C%5Cnew%5C%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%28%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%28%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%28%7B%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%7D%29?%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%7D%29?%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%7D%29?%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%5C%7D&input=%5Cnew%7B%7D%5Cnew%7B%5Ctextbf%7B%5Ctextbf%7B%5Ctextbf%7Btest1%7D%7D%7D%7D%5Cnew%7Btest2%7D)

Comment: If you're like me and want to search for braces containing a maximum of one nested group of braced arguments, then this will work copy-pasted into your search bar in TexStudio with Regex enabled: ```\{[^\{\}]*(\{[^\{\}]*\})?[^\{\}]*\}```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Sadly, this solution won't match nested pattern like `\new{\foo{text}}`.

As far as I know matching balanced patterns with regex requires recursive patterns, and if TeXStudio doesn't support lazy quantifiers I doubt it will support those.

This is not about translating `\\new\{(.*?)\}`: on your testcase this would return `\textbf{test1test2`.

I think you'll have to find another tool than TeXStudio regex to do what you want.

---

Since it seems pretty limited I don't know if TeXStudio supports it, but if your text doesn't contain `}` you can use

```
\\new\{([^}]*)\}
```

`[^}]` meaning "anything but a `}`". No need for lazy quantifier this way.

If that doesn't work I guess you could try to take the problem from another angle and replace `\new{` and `}` with an empty string... Depends on your input, you might not want to break the rest of your code.

If your input really is a list a `\new{}` following each other, you might want to try a version of `} *\new{` to avoid replacing other unwanted `}`, and do a couple cases by hand?

Comment: Thanks. \\new\{([^}]*)\} particialy works. But I also have something like \new{\\textbf{test}} in my tex. So it still has problems. I tried \\new\{([^(\\new)]*)\}. But it does not work either. Is that my expression is problematic? I mean is there a way in regex to say I need a substring that does not contained "\new{"

Comment: @Leo: So you want to match nested patterns... Please update your original post with these examples, this is a very different question if the `text` can contain balanced `{...}`

Comment: @Robin Thanks. I just added the example and added one \new{\textbf{test1}}.