# Regex how to match a substring that does not contain a fixed string. Regex in TexStudio:

Tags: regex, substring, match

I want to a regex expression to replace the following string

```
{match1}{matchb}{not}{anotb}
```

with

```
match1matchb{not}{anotb}}
```

How to write the regex expression.

Basically I want to find a string inside `{}` but the string can not contain `not`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the regex `\{(?![^}]*not)([^}]+)\}`

And replace with `$1` or `\1` based on your regex engine(or the function).

In the regex `(?![^}]*not)` is a negative lookahead that is checking that there is no `not` inside the `{}`.

Try it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gY5eD2).

Comment: @Sabuj Hassan Good one. It solved this question. However, I found it still has some problem in dealing a general problem in my mind: how to use regex to mimic non-greedy match even if non-greedy match is not supported by an editor. Can you have a look at my full problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963781/texstudio-how-to-do-the-smallest-match-in-regex-replace/22963955?noredirect=1#comment35063894_22963955

Answer (score 0):

You can match this:

`\{([^}]*)\}\{([^}]*)\}\{not\}`

and replace with:

`\1\2{not}`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/uA8rU9

Comment: This is just a sub-question. Can you have a look at my full problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963781/texstudio-how-to-do-the-smallest-match-in-regex-replace/22963955?noredirect=1#comment35063894_22963955